# Is it possible to clip transparent images that are behind other transparent images

Tags: html, css, image, transparency, clipping

I need it where my relections don't overlap. I'm currently using figures and box reflect:

```css
.scene .carousel figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    line-height: 116px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.scene .carousel figure {
    background: black;
}

.carousel-image {
    content: "";
    background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px linear-gradient(transparent 60%, white 200%);
}
```

```html
<figure key={i} style={Util.figureStyle(d)} >
                    <img src={d.info.jpg} alt={d.info ? d.info.name : ""} height={"100%"} widht={"100%"} className='carousel-image' />
                </figure>
```

So my question is basically using this method how do I clip the reflections behind the one closest to the top layer?

[image: ![Here are the reflections]

I came up with a possible band-aid solution for now which is to add another div element that simply whites out behind the transparent images.

```css
.clip-background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    bottom: -100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<figure key={i} style={Util.figureStyle(d)} >
                    <img src={d.info.jpg} alt={d.info ? d.info.name : ""} height={"100%"} widht={"100%"} className='carousel-image' />
                    <div className='clip-background' />
                </figure>
```

[image: What the image looks like after]

I'm gonna leave this open in case there's a better solution. Something else I was wondering is if I can have the nearest child reflection be more vibrant without setting an individual reflection for each child in the carousel, This would ad to the reflection looking more realistic.

Comment: A bit more CSS and HTML would be helpful!

Comment: alright give me a minute